# Сосна, ель, пихта, кедр — словом, все породы хвойных деревьев встречаются в сибирской тайге

Tags: пунктуация

Если после тире стоят слова, выделяющиеся по существующим правилам запятыми (например, вводные слова), то первая запятая опускается?

Answer (score 3):

Вы абсолютно правы, первая запятая опускается.

Если перед обобщающим словом, отделенным от однородных членов посредством тире, имеется вводное слово, то запятая перед вводным словом опускается: **В вестибюле, в коридоре, в кабинетах — словом, всюду толпились люди (Поп.).**

> См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!